# Bootstrap: full width background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in html:

```css
.class4{
  height: 650px; background-color: SlateGrey; padding-top: 8px;padding-left: 20px; 
}

h1.b{
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:Segoe WP Semibold
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid class4">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <h1 class="b" id="ABOUT">ABOUT</h1><hr width="87%">
        <br><br>
        <div class="container"> 
          <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 "><p style="color:white"><span style="font-size:120%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit vo- luptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</span><br><br><br><span style="font-size:80%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold"> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam elus modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore <br>magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum <br> exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?<br><br>

            Quis autem vei eum lure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nlhil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
              <img src="C:/Users/user/Desktop/images/7.jpg" alt="image">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This code displays a text and an image over a background on the laptop screen: the text to the left and the image to the right

The problem is when I do `inspect` to see the result on a mobile device, the background doesn't cover the full width and a big part of the image seems to be out of the background

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the image going out to the right, you need to make the size responsive by setting the width to 100%. To fix that the background is not covering the entire page, you need to remove the defined height.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.class4{
background-color: SlateGrey; padding-top: 8px;padding-left: 20px; 
}

h1.b{ text-align: center;
         color:white;
         font-weight: bold;
         font-family:Segoe WP Semibold}

         .responsive {
           width: 100%;
         }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid class4"><br><br><br><br><h1 class = "b" id="ABOUT">ABOUT</h1><hr width="87%">
<br><br>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 "><p style="color:white"><span style="font-size:120%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit vo- luptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</span><br><br><br><span style="font-size:80%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold"> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam elus modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore <br>magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum <br> exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?<br><br>

Quis autem vei eum lure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nlhil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum</span></p></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 "><img class="responsive" src="https://i.redd.it/b62rivs3uyo11.jpg" alt="" ></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to set the img width to `100%`. Since you are using bootstrap, you can add [`class="w-100"`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row) to the img.

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/v690mpcs/)

```css
.class4 {
  height: 650px;
  background-color: SlateGrey;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

h1.b {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Segoe WP Semibold
}

.w-100 {width: 100%}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid class4"><br><br><br><br>
  <h1 class="b" id="ABOUT">ABOUT</h1>
  <hr width="87%">
  <br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
        <p style="color:white"><span style="font-size:120%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit vo- luptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</span><br><br><br><span style="font-size:80%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold"> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam elus modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore <br>magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum <br> exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?<br><br>

Quis autem vei eum lure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nlhil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 "><img class="w-100" src="https://i.redd.it/b62rivs3uyo11.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: You may also want to switch from `col-xs-6` to `col-xs-12`, so bootstrap can use all 12 columns of its grid.

Comment: @user10254054 Glad to be helpful. Feel free to upvote and valid the answer. By the way if you can, upgrade to bootstrap4 :)

Answer (score 1):

To make it responsive to mobile, I changed `col-xs-6` to `col-xs-12` to both of the elements, and then I added `width: 100%`. Look at the following example:

```css
.class4{
  height: 650px; background-color: SlateGrey; padding-top: 8px;padding-left: 20px; 
}

h1.b{
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:Segoe WP Semibold
}

.w-100 {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid class4">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <h1 class="b" id="ABOUT">ABOUT</h1><hr width="87%">
        <br><br>
        <div class="container"> 
          <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 "><p style="color:white"><span style="font-size:120%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit vo- luptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</span><br><br><br><span style="font-size:80%;font-family:Segoe WP Semibold"> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam elus modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore <br>magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum <br> exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?<br><br>

            Quis autem vei eum lure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nlhil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_960_720.jpg" alt="image" class="w-100">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Use `w-100` from bootstrap instead. Check my answer to see how to.

Comment: @aloisdg I didn't see that bootstrap 3 has `w-100`. Although, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"` to the img. And it will work properly.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 "><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="C:/Users/user/Desktop/images/7.jpg" alt="" ></div>
```